# Any way to draw separate dynamic stimuli for consecutive frames at the same time? (psychopy)

Tags: python, psychopy

I'm trying to display a set of numbers that change dynamically over the course of about 25 seconds while at the same time displaying visual stimuli that serves as feedback for the subjects' responses. However, it appears that the script is not able to perform both tasks at once. Can anyone think of any kind of work around for this? Any help is very appreciated. I'm very new to python/psychopy, so I apologize if the code is a little messy.

Here's my current code:

**Begin Routine**

```
if not countdownStartedIndie:
   countdownClock = core.CountdownTimer(26)
   countdownStartedIndie = True

if not countupto:
    timer = core.Clock()
    avgtaps = 0
    countupto = True
```

**Each Frame**

```
timeRemaining = countdownClock.getTime()  
ValueWin = visual.TextStim(win, text='+', font='', pos=(-0.5, -0.5), depth=0, rgb=None, color=('limegreen'), colorSpace='rgb', opacity=1, contrast=1.0, units='', ori=0.0, height=0.3, antialias=True, bold=False, italic=False, alignHoriz='center', alignVert='center', fontFiles=(), wrapWidth=None, flipHoriz=False, flipVert=False, name=None, autoLog=None)
```

`timetogo = timer.getTime()`

```
if timetogo >= 25:
    countupto = False
else:
    minutes2 = int(timetogo/60)
    seconds2 = int(timetogo -(minutes2*60))

if timeRemaining <= 0.0:
    s4.finished = True
    continueRoutine = False
    countdownStartedIndie = False
else:
    minutes = int(timeRemaining/60) # the integer number of minutes
    seconds = int(timeRemaining -(minutes*60))
    timeText = str(minutes)+ ':' + str(seconds) #create a string of characters representing time

if s4keys.corr:
   ValueWin.draw #visual player feedback

jitter = [10,11,12,13][randint(0,3)]
groupcount = 'x' + str(jitter)
for frameN in range (48):
   s4count.draw() #a text stim using the 'groupcount' variable 
   win.flip()
```

Comment: Hi @aubrey welcome to StackOverflow. Please describe *exactly* what you do want to appear and *exactly* what " it appears that the script is not able to perform both tasks at once" means.

Answer (score 0):

I can provide a more general example, which you can hopefully adapt to your situation. Hopefully, by cutting it to the bone, the general principle is easier to understand.

```py
# Set up modules and stimuli
from psychopy import visual, event
win = visual.Window()
stim = visual.TextStim(win, text='I\'m a stimulus!')
feedback = visual.TextStim(win, text='')

for frame in range(5*60):  # Run for 5 seconds on a 60 Hz monitor
    # Change stimulus dynamically
    stim.pos += (0.001, 0.002)  # Change position
    stim.color -= 0.005  # Make darker

    # Feedback based on response
    key = event.getKeys()
    if key:
        feedback.text = 'Last key was %s' %key[0]

    # Show it
    stim.draw()
    feedback.draw()
    win.flip()
```

Naturally, you could have more stimuli, do more elaborate feedback, change more features, etc. In your case, you would probably change the stimulus text instead of position and color.